# How to define an enum has multiple value that is another enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have two enum like below. But I don't know I can define enum like below. I tried. It seems to work. My first question. Can I define an enum like below ?

```
[Flags]
public enum SState : int
{
    ManuelPassive = 2501601,
    AutoPassive = 2501602,
    ManuelActive = 2501610,
    AutoActive = 2501611,
}

public enum SType : int
{
    All,
    Active = SState .AutoActive | SState .ManuelActive,
    Passive = SState .AutoPassive | SState .ManuelPassive,
}
```

My second question : If I can define this enum, How can I convert a `SType` value to `SState` list ?

```
public statis List<SState> ToList(this SType stype)
{
    // What should I do here ? 
}
```

Example Calling :

```
var list = SType.Active.ToList();
```

I want this list to be like below :

```
var list = new List<SState>{ SState.AutoActive, SState.ManuelActive };
```

Comment: Can you change `SState` values? I would embed type into it, few bits to define which type it is. Then masks to get either value or type. As you doing it now `SType` only needs 3 values (they have nothing to do with `SState`) and conversion is a simple switch/case.

Comment: `SState.AutoActive` = `SState.ManuelActive + 1`. This means that if some enum variable value is `SState.AutoActive`, then by default it has a flag of value `SState.ManuelActive`? Is this intentional?

Comment: If you need lists of values, what is the reason to declare them as enum instead of `List`s?

Comment: @Sinatr  Unfortunately, I cannot change those values.

Comment: @Dmitry Yes. I can use list of values. I just wonder I can use this way ? It is possible ?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sorry. I didn't get your comment.

Comment: Assume that you have a `var a = SState.AutoActive;`, this means that `a` has two flags: `SState.AutoActive` and `SState.ManuelActive`.

Comment: `a.HasFlag(SState.AutoActive);` would be `true` and `a.HasFlag(SState.ManuelActive);` would also be `true`.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Yes. I can has two flags. But Values are not intentional. (+1) is not valid rule.

Comment: Can you change these values to 1,2,4,8?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Sorry, I cannot change.

Comment: As it is, it will not work. Consider that `AutoActive` = `ManuelPassive + 10`. Why would `SType.Active.ToList()` not include `ManuelPassive` also?

Answer (score 2):

The first question is fine - it will compile without problems as long as you don't have a circular definition.

Your second question is more interesting - one solution is to use the [Type-Safe Enumeration pattern](http://blog.falafel.com/introducing-type-safe-enum-pattern/) popularised by Java.

This pattern allows you to add new behaviours to your enums (something a language like Swift supports out of the box, but C# and Java sadly don't). In the below example I have given your enum a `Value` and a `List` property, as requested.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(SType.Active.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(SType.Active.List);
}

[Flags]
public enum SState : int
{
    ManuelPassive = 2501601,
    AutoPassive = 2501602,
    ManuelActive = 2501610,
    AutoActive = 2501611,
}

public sealed class SType
{
    public static readonly SType Active = new SType(new List<SState>() { SState.AutoActive, SState.ManuelActive });

    public static readonly SType Passive = new SType(new List<SState>() { SState.AutoPassive, SState.ManuelPassive });

    private SType (List<SState> values)
    {
        this.Value = (int)values.Aggregate((current, next) => current | next);
        this.List = values;
    }

    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public List<SState> List { get; private set; }
}
```